# Different behavior in parsing LaTeX code in the previewer and in the saved post

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I posted  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9820/doubt-inequality-almost-everywhere/9821#9821) a few minutes ago. After the display, I had written `$\int_E f\\,d\mu$` to get the thin space; the previewer parsed it correctly (and parsed it incorrectly without the double backslash, displaying the comma instead). After I saved, if I had `\\,` then the post complained of a misplaced `\\` and did not display the formula; if I had the single backslash, `\,`, then it displayed correctly.

In other words, the previewer was doing one thing, while the final display was doing another.

Comment: It just happened again with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9825/does-this-property-characterize-a-space-as-hausdorff, this time with `\\{` which displayed correctly in the previewer, but led to complaints after it was saved; removing the double backslash led to incorrect display in the previewer, correct when saved.

Comment: I suspect, though I have no official information, that you may be experiencing the results of some attempts at "fixing" the need for the doubled-backslashes inside `$`.

Comment: My problem in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/if-i-t-1-exists-can-it-always-be-written-in-a-series-representation/9837#9837 might be related to this error.

Comment: I've run into other problems with displayed equations using `$$`. I have no objection to settling on either behaviour, but the fact that the preview and the server are behaving differently is a definite problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is new behavior.  All content between `$$` on sites with LaTeX rendering enabled will not be converted from markdown.  This means it is no longer necessary to escape `\` or other special markdown sequences.

This only applies to newly created (or edited) posts, old posts will continue to render correctly.

<s>Currently the post preview pane still shows the old behavior (similar to the new [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) syntax).  A fix for this is planned.</s>

The preview should correctly ignore content between `$$` now.

Comment: If a fix is planned, then is it really status-bydesign?

Comment: @Isaac - yes, if only for a lack of [status-expect-additional-improvement-in-the-future].

Comment: Isn't that what [status-deferred] is for?

Comment: Well, I hope the previewer gets updated soon; I'm going to be doing a lot of edits until then...

Comment: Great! Thanks for the work. Can this be extended to environments (`\begin{stuff}...\end{stuff}`) as well?